# Continue from a Async Generator in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Given a regular generator, you can get an iterator from it that can only be consumed once and continue where you left off. Like this -

```
sync_gen = (i in range(10))
def fetch_batch_sync(num_tasks, job_list):
    for i, job in enumerate(job_list):
        yield job
        if i == num_tasks - 1:
            break
>>> sync_gen_iter = sync_gen.__iter__()
>>> for i in fetch_batch_sync(2, sync_gen_iter):
...     print i
... 
0
1
>>> for i in fetch_batch_sync(3, sync_gen_iter):
...     print i
... 
2
3
4
```

Is there a way to do the same with an async generator?

```
async def fetch_batch_async(num_tasks, job_list_iter):
    async for i, job in enumerate(job_list_iter):
        yield job
        if i == num_tasks - 1:
            break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between regular and async generators is that async generators' equivalents of `__next__` and `__iter__` methods are themselves async. This is why ordinary `for` and `enumerate` fail to recognize them as iterables.

As with regular generators, it is possible to extract a subset of values out of an async generator, but you need to use the appropriate tools. `fetch_batch_async` already uses `async for`, but it should also use an async version of `enemuerate`; for example:

```
async def aenumerate(aiterable, start=0):
    i = start
    async for obj in aiterable:
        yield i, obj
        i += 1
```

`fetch_batch_async` would use it exactly like `enumerate`:

```
async def fetch_batch_async(num_tasks, job_list_iter):
    async for i, job in aenumerate(job_list_iter):
        yield job
        if i == num_tasks - 1:
            break
```

Finally, this code uses `fetch_batch_async` to extract several items out of an infinite async iterator:

```
import asyncio, time

async def infinite():
    while True:
        yield time.time()
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)

async def main():
    async for received in fetch_batch_async(10, infinite()):
        print(received)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify for the others, object of an AsyncGeneratorType can only be iterated once (duh!).